# Read JSON URL in Twitch IRC bot

Tags: java, json, url, inputstream

I'm working on a Twitch IRC Bot and right now I need to make a function which will check if a stream either is online or offline.

I've came up with some code now but I always get "null" back even while the stream is online.

What i run in my Main Class:

```
public void LiveChecker() { 
    TTtwl.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TwitchLiveChecker();
            System.out.println(TwitchLiveChecker.json);
            System.out.println(TwitchLiveChecker.json);
        }
    }, 1000*10, 1000*10);
}
```

My Twitch Live checker Class:
    package YBot;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class TwitchLiveChecker {

    public static JSONObject json;

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    json = readJsonFromUrl("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel="+MyBot.ownerchannel+"");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("id"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `null`? What is `null`? Give us your expectations, give us your actual results.

Comment: public void TwitchLiveChecker() {
  
  TTtwl.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {


     TwitchLiveChecker();
     
       System.out.println(TwitchLiveChecker.json);
       System.out.println(TwitchLiveChecker.json);

       
     }
     }, 1000*10, 1000*10);
 }

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Also, please don't post code in comments. It's incredibly hard to read.

Comment: whenever i call the class and printout the json object its null.

Comment: Is the new code related to the old code? You don't seem to send the HTTP request in the new code. So the `json` fields remains `null`. Also, it seems like you have an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: modified my text above a bit.  Im trying to receive two statements while the stream is online and offline so i can write an if online.. / if offline.. method.

Comment: im not? oh..  its a code snippet i came up with through google/other threads.. may u tell me what is wrong actually or how i fix this?

Comment: You have to call the `readJsonFromUrl` method and assign its return value to `TwitchLiveChecker.json` before you use it.

Comment: may u give me an code example? im still a beginner in java and im a bit confused now :o

Comment: No, I won't give you a code example. That will get you nowhere. It seems like you jumped into the hard stuff a little prematurely. Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) with the basic Java tutorials.

Comment: im still learning. if u tell me whats wrong with my code i will learn more instead of searching whats wrong and get no results In my opinion the code should work how it is :/

Comment: Awwm I Found and error.. The Timer actually calls itself again. xD  nvm. Other Question is then: how can i "run" the other class now?